# How to crop the same ROI in a rectangle with different sizes

Tags: python, opencv, crop

I want to crop some regions (ROIs) of images, i am currently extracting from images a rectangle shape and in this shape i want to extract some ROIs that are always in the same local but the rectangle/image will have different resolutions but the same porportion (ID Card porpotion) so i can not use fixed coordenates like i am currently doing:

```
 ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) = box.position

 print(box.position)

 cv.rectangle(cvImage, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
```

But this will not work in all images, i think i already made the point :)

How i can use like % or something similar to always get the same spots in the rectangle regardless of resolution/size of the rectangle.

Thank you.

Comment: use the function findContours. it will give you the coordinates of the rectangular figure in the image regardless of size

Comment: But that rectangular figure will have different resolutions depending on the original image, because of that i cant use fixed coordinates.

Comment: You are not using fixed coordinates. findContours will give you different coordinates depending on where the corners of the rectangles are located.

Comment: I am not getting it :( I am already cropping the rectangle i want from the image, now how can i get some ROIs that are always in same place on the rectangle but the rectangle is different sizes ?

Comment: give us a sample image and we can discuss further.  findContour will give you all rectangles you need.

Comment: Compute the center of the rectangle. Then add/subtract half the widths that you want for the rectangle to get the top left and bottom right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can always select the same proportions of an image. For instance, extract a rectangle with coordinates defined by a fixed ratio (or percentage)

```
img_w = 1000 # = cvImage.width
img_h = 1000 # = cvImage.height
tl_x = 10.0 / 100.0
tl_y = 10.0 / 100.0
br_x = 90.0 / 100.0
br_y = 90.0 / 100.0

print (tl_x, tl_y, br_x, br_y)

rect_tl = (int(tl_x * img_w), int(tl_y * img_h))
rect_br = (int(br_x * img_w), int(br_y * img_h))

print (rect_tl, rect_br)

#cv.rectangle(cvImage, rect_tl, rect_br, (255,0,0), 2)
```

This will compute the coordinates of a rectangle in an image of size 1000x1000, but it is a variable defined as img_w x img_h

The hardcoded rectangle is placed with 10% padding, defined using top-left & bottom-right corners

As expected the output is :

```
0.1 0.1 0.9 0.9
(100, 100) (900, 900)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can resize the image you read,and can crop same regions:

```
image = cv2.imread("image,jpg")
resize_image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480)) 
...
```